# Knockoutjs component with template depend on ViewModel

Tags: knockout.js, components

I have a problem, but i coun't find the way to solve with knockout component.

I want to write a form-control component, I using AMD to register component on demand

I register component

```
ko.components.register('form-control', {require: 'com/form-control/form-control'});
```

form-control.js

```
define(['knockout'],function(ko){
    var template = '<div></div>';
    function Control(params){
        this.editor = params.editor;
        **// I want load template using ajax depend on this.edior, but, ajax call is async, I got component with no template if template = '';**
    };

    Control.prototype.dispose = function() { };

    return { viewModel: Control, template: template}; });
```

I want using in form:

```
<form>
    <form-control params='field:"name",editor:"textbox"'></form-control>
    <form-control params='field:"desc",editor:"textarea"'></form-control>
<form>
```

Please help me, I want to use ajax call to load template depend on editor from viewModel, I think that could be load from template DOM ID element, but that's not a good solution in this case.

Comment: Can you please post more code, where are you using the component. What does your requirejs config look like? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Knockout components are usually the combination of one ViewModel constructor and one Template (usually, since you can do it differently if you create a custom component loader). Knockout even caches the template definition (this is described in the documentation). If you want the same component to use different templates depending on a value in the viewmodel you probably need do it inside the component and use a template such as `<div data-bind="template: editor"></div>` and google for async loading of templates in knockout.

Comment: However, shouldn't the textbox and the textarea rather be different components? You can register the same viewmodel constructor for multiple components with different templates. In my view, this would make your code easier to read and maintain and also skip problems such as the one you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Your experience is good for me right now.

Comment: I agree with @RobertWesterlund. Here is an [example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/AnishPatelUk/fps2jm26/)